# Compile Matcaffe error: undefined reference to boost::thread::join()

Tags: linux, boost, caffe, matcaffe

I am new here and this is my very first question. I started working on deep learning recently and decided to use caffe. I went through the steps as explained in the caffe tutorial installation: installed CUDA, cuDNN, installed OpenBLAS, the other libraries and so on. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. After that I downloaded caffe and tried to compile it. Everything seemed fine until I got this error message:

.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so/ undefined reference to boost::thread::join()

I know this is a linking problem. I installed the boost libraries from the terminal with sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev.  I have been looking around for a while, but I have not found anything specific to help me. What exactly do I need to do: create some soft-link (seemed like one of the main ways to solve this problem), change my Makefile (I already fixed it so that it looks where the boost library is) or something else?

Thanks in advance